# django_q_task saves too much records

Tags: django, django-q

I am having a problem with my `djang_q_task` table. It saves too many records than expected.

I have config like below:

```
Q_CLUSTER = {
    'name': 'xxxx',
    'workers': 8,
    'recycle': 500,
    'timeout': 600,
    'compress': True,
    'save_limit': 250,
    'queue_limit': 500,
    'cpu_affinity': 1,
    'label': 'Django Q',....
```

With the `save_limit` as 250, I am having more than 1M records in the `django_q_task` table.

Anyone knows why does it save too many records? That causes me some memory issues.

best regards,
Thanh Tran

Comment: That config option "Limits the amount of successful tasks saved", so what exactly is it that your task does? Perhaps the task does multiple saves and the task runs multiple times given that the limit on tasks is 250?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help! My task is just saving a record to the dabase

Comment: Can you try running `./manage.py dbshell` and the SQL query `select success, count(*) from django_q_task group by success;` ? This will tell us how many are successes and how many are failures.